# Searching for value in a text file then printing the next line

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am importing a txt file into Python 3, I am able to successfully print the item/line I am using as an identifier, however I am having difficulty printing the following line and retaining that value.

I am using `'Anchor'` to find the line items which follow. The number of lines between each `'Anchor'` varies, meaning sometimes there is junk/noise between `'Anchor'`, however the depth and distance from shore are always the same number of lines from Anchor. I tried to add 1 to line, as the if function lets me know that it is an `'Anchor'` value, however I get the following:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

The file looks similar to:

```
asfasdfasdf
Anchor
The depth is 30 Feet
5 miles from shore

asdfasdsf
Anchor
The depth is 24 feet
8 miles from shore
Anchor
The depth is 21 feet
4 km from shore
```

Attempting with the following code:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')

for line in f.readlines():
    if 'Anchor' in line:
        print(line+1)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a variable representing the state of the last line, like this:

```
previous_line_was_anchor = False
for line in f.readlines():
    if 'Anchor' in line:
        previous_line_was_anchor = True
    else: 
        if previous_line_was_anchor:
             print line
        previous_line_was_anchor = False
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, any thoughts on how to print additional line items following 'Anchor'?

Comment: That was not part of your original question. You should accept the answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [python iterators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterator#iterator-types).

It looks like your problem would be more suited to a custom iteration, rather than using a `for .. in ..` loop:

```
lines = iter(f.readlines())

while True:
    try:
        if next(lines) == 'Anchor':
            print(next(lines))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

If you need to print additional lines after 'Anchor' just add more `print(next(lines))` calls.